# Android Studio version control using github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, version

I've just setup github and was playing around with pushing a simple test project to github. 
For my tests, I have pushed 3 versions of the project (v1, v2, v3 being the latest).

When I try to pull my project from github, Android Studio automatically pulls the latest version (v3).

Let's say that the latest version had some major issues and I now need to go back and pull the previous one (v2).

How can I pull any of the other versions instead of the latest one?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Pull will also give you the latest commit. If you want v2, you need to check out that commit for v2. You can read more about git and probably some examples from google.